# Animation doesnt keep final state, switches back to original state

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm learning Angular 6 at the moment and ran into a bit of a problem. I'm using this tutorial: https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html

When i click the button, the animation triggers as expected, but after the fade out the text pops up back again. Any ideas why it switches back to the original state?

[image]

Thanks in advance

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle Fade</button>
<div [@someCoolAnimation]="bindingVar">hello there</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {trigger, transition, style, animate} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('someCoolAnimation', [
      transition('* => fadeIn', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(1000, style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition('* => fadeOut', [
        animate(1000, style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  bindingVar = '';
  fadeIn() {
    this.bindingVar = 'fadeIn';
  }
  fadeOut() {
    this.bindingVar = 'fadeOut';
  }
  toggle() {
    this.bindingVar == 'fadeOut' ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `state` from angular animations. It will enforce styles when the animation is in a given state. You can see the official example here https://angular.io/guide/animations#transitioning-between-two-states

Make sure you import the state

```
import { ... state } from '@angular/animations';
```

State is used like this

```
animations: [
    trigger('someCoolAnimation', [
      state('fadeIn'
      //enforce your styles for the fadeIn state here
          style({ opacity: 1 })
      ),
      state('fadeOut'
      //enforce your styles for fadeOut state here
          style({ opacity: 0 })
      )
      transition('* => fadeIn', [
        animate(1000)
      ]),
      transition('* => fadeOut', [
        animate(1000)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Answer (score -1):

My issue was caused by setting a value without `px` on the end that requires it.

**This BREAKS** - resets the margin its initial value after the animation:

```
state('open', style({
    marginLeft: '-100'
}))
```

**This WORKS!!!**

```
state('open', style({
    marginLeft: '-100px'
}))
```